# Ansible - return code of commands launch into a loop from machines variables

Tags: ansible

I have some serious struggle with my Ansible tasks right now, i think i need a little bit of help ...

The background : 
I have multiple servers in my Ansible inventory, and i want to be able to launch a playbook that check the status of the services running on the servers, without making specific tasks for each services.
I have configure the machines variables to look like this (for example) :

```
services:
  apache-custom:
   cmd: ps aux | grep /bin/custom-httpd | ps -efl | grep custom-owner | grep -v grep
   return_code: 0
   restart: echo restart
  mysqld:
   cmd: 0
```

And the playbook is currently the following :

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Check native services status
      service:
        name: "{{ item.key }}"
        state: started
       with_dict: "{{ services }}"
       when: item.value.cmd == 0

    - name: Check others services
      shell: "{{ item.value.cmd }}"
      register: result
      with_dict: "{{ services }}"
      failed_when: result.rc != item.value.return_code
      when: item.value.cmd != 0 and item.value.cmd != ''
      ignore_errors: yes
```

For the services defined with 'cmd: 0', the first task is going to check the status of the service, and launch it if not started. 
But for some custom services, the 'service' module cannot help me, so i need to launch command in order to know if the service is start.
The second task is working in this case, but i'm unable to grab the return code of that task in order to launch the task that is going to start the service.

I tried to add this task :

```
- name: test
  debug:
    msg: ({{ item.item.key }}) failed
  when: item.rc != 0
  with_items: "{{ result.results }}"
```

But Ansible is complaining about the fact that a 'dict' value don't have any return code.

I tried to debug, and i don't understand what's going on.
For example, when i want to see the content of the global result of my tasks, i add this :

```
- name: test2
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ result.results }}"
```

it gave me the following output (that contain the return code that i'm looking for) :

```
[...]
     "failed_when_result": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "ps aux | grep /bin/custom-httpd | ps -efl | grep custom_owner | grep -v grep",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "item": {
        "key": "apache-custom",
        "value": {
            "cmd": "ps aux | grep /bin/custom_httpd | ps -efl | grep custom-owner | grep -v grep",
            "restart": "echo restart",
            "return_code": 0
        }
    },
    "rc": 0, <====== here is the return code
    "start": "2018-07-09 15:44:24.859555",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    [...]
```

But i can't reach it ...

Any idea how to do that ?
Or am i doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend to write a shell script to take care of returning proper code status for your custom services rather than putting that into ansible, and call this script from ansible with the list of custom services.

Comment: Thanks for you replay, but theire is somthing that i don't understand : Why this return code value that i need is in front of me when i diplay the content of me 'result.results', but why did it still unreachable ? If Ansible show me this variable, i should be able to play with it ...

Comment: Please edit the question, clarify "I'm unable to grab the return code of that task in order to launch the task that is going to start the service" and the various error your faced

Comment: you shouldn't check `item.rc` which is the global status of the task, but rather `item.value.return_code` which is is for each services passed to the task.

Comment: `item.value.return_code` is a custom variable that i want to use for comparing the actual return code with. It's the return code expected for this command !

Answer (score 0):

"To be able to launch a playbook that check the status of the services running on the servers" you might want to consider the module *service_facts*.

```
- name: 'Test service_facts'
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: populate service facts
      service_facts:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_facts.services
```